# Share Service Between Two Different Modules and two different js files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have checked many questions but no one clearly give examples which uses different js files.
I am working on angular js, and I'm stuck in the following issue.
Issue is, I want to Call functions which is in different js file and has different modules.
Now I Create "Service",which handles both modules and both functions,here is my Code,

First Module in first.js

```
var TaskAPP = angular.module('TaskApp', []);
TaskAPP.factory("TestService", function () {
    var users = ["ad", "bf", "tt"];
    return {
        all: function () {
            return users;
        },
        first: function () {
            return users[0];
        }
    };
});
```

second module in second.js

```
var LabAPP = angular.module('LabApp', ['TaskApp', 'TestService']);
  LabAPP.controller("LabController", function ($scope, TestService) {
       $scope.aa = TestService.first();
});
```

but here on this page,error occur Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
Can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

Your `TestService` is defined on `TaskAPP`, which is why it can't be used in `LabApp`. The solution is to create a module just for services, you want shared across modules.

For example, create a module just to hold shareable services:

```
angular.module('SharedServices', [])
.service('TestService', function(){
 // code
 }
```

Then inject  `SharedServices` module into whichever module you want to access the service from:

```
angular.module('TaskAPP', ['SharedServices'])
```

Then access the service you want using `SharedServices.TestService.fooMethod()`

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is to use the service name `TestService` as a module dependency - this line:

```
var LabAPP = angular.module('LabApp', ['TaskApp', 'TestService']);
```

This fails, because there is no module called `TestService`, there is only a service *inside* the module `TaskApp` with that name. This should work:

```
var LabAPP = angular.module('LabApp', ['TaskApp']);
  LabAPP.controller("LabController", function ($scope, TestService) {
       $scope.aa = TestService.first();
});
```

Love from Switzerland :)